# Query based on dates and MAX values, help greatly appreciated

Tags: sql

I have this problem on my hands that I cannot quite figure out the best way to solve. We have a database of students and their study entitlements. Each student has unique studentId and for each student there can be 1-N amount of study entitlements, some might have over 10 for example. Each entitlement has an end date.

So what we would like to achieve is a query that results **one row per student** with the following conditions. I am using MS SQL.

- if student has only one entitlement, return that
- if they have multiple, return the one with furthest end date
- if multiple entitlements have the same MAX end date, return the one with largest entitlement number

In the example below, ideally it would return the following rows:

Row 2 for Aaron A

Row 4 for Charlie C

Row 5 for Frank F

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

| row | studentId | studentName | entitlementId | entitlementEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | Aaron A | 100500 | 2021-12-31 |
| 2 | 100 | Aaron A | 200600 | 2021-12-31 |
| 3 | 200 | Charlie C | 300800 | 2021-10-31 |
| 4 | 200 | Charlie C | 400900 | 2022-01-31 |
| 5 | 300 | Frank F | 500100 | 2022-09-31 |
| 6 | 300 | Frank F | 500900 | 2021-02-31 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY studentId
                                   ORDER BY entitlementEndDate DESC, entitlementId DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT row, studentId, studentName, entitlementId, entitlementEndDate
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all 2022-09-31 and 2021-02-31 are quite strange dates... so I will substitute them for 2022-09-30 and 2021-02-28.

That said, your query should be:

```
with cte (rowId, [row], studentId, studentName, entitlementId, entitlementEndDate)
as
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by studentId order by entitlementEndDate desc,entitlementId desc),* from MyTable
)
select [row], studentId, studentName, entitlementId, entitlementEndDate from cte where rowId = 1
```

This would return:
| row | studentId |studentName | entitlementId | entitlementEndDate |
| ----------- | ----------- | -------------------------------------------------- | ------------- | ------------------ |
| 2           | 100         | Aaron A                                            |200600        |2021-12-31|
| 4           | 200         | Charlie C                                          |400900        |2022-01-31|
| 5           |300         |Frank F                                            |500100        | 2022-09-30|

You can check it with this code (it would be useful for future questions if you paste this code directly):

```
create table #MyTable (
    [row] int,
    studentId int,
    studentName varchar(50), 
    entitlementId   int,
    entitlementEndDate date
)

insert into #MyTable values (1, 100, 'Aaron A', 100500, '2021-12-31'),
(2  ,100    ,'Aaron A', 200600, '2021-12-31'),
(3  ,200    ,'Charlie C',   300800, '2021-10-31'),
(4  ,200    ,'Charlie C',   400900, '2022-01-31'),
(5  ,300    ,'Frank F', 500100, '2022-09-30'),
(6  ,300    ,'Frank F', 500900, '2021-02-28');

with cte (rowId, [row], studentId, studentName, entitlementId, entitlementEndDate)
as
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by studentId order by entitlementEndDate desc,entitlementId desc),* from #MyTable
)
select [row], studentId, studentName, entitlementId, entitlementEndDate from cte where rowId = 1
```

Comment: Thank you :) About those dates - I just hastily wrote some data and didn't really check if they are valid dates since in the example it really didn't matter.